# jazz cash payment gateway getting responce "[pp_ResponseCode] => FE34" ,redirecting to return url instead to payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, merchant-account

jazz cash payment gateway getting responce "[pp_ResponseCode] => FE34" ,redirecting to return url instead to payment gateway.

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTN65.png)//i.stack.imgur.com/6mSsz.png

Answer (score 0):

Now JazzCash restricts sandbox testing can only be done on **live and SSL-secured** websites.

Comment: what's the reference to this information?

Comment: I have contacted the support team. You can contact them via this email merchantsupport@jazzcash.com.pk

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this issue?? I am getting the same response code "FE34". What is the reason of this error??